# Samba share not accessable from other subnets

Tags: linux, centos, samba, subnets

Thanks for taking a look to my issue and think with me for a solution.
I have a samba server on a subnet 172.23.3.55/23 (2.0 --> 3.255) and within that subnet I can access the server no problem.
Also the 172.23.4.0/23 subnet that lives on the same Core Switch can access the server no problem.
Even our Office Subnet 129.228.114.0/23 can access the system through the firewall with no issue. But when I connect to our VPN network, 172.23.45.0/24 or when I come from a different office with totally different ranges I cannot access the server. The server responds, and I need to login, but the login is rejected always.

Here is my [global] and [share] section of the smb.conf

```
        workgroup = localdomain.nmc
        netbios name = AMS-QTGW02
        server string = %h server (Samba %v)
#        hosts allow = 172.23.202.0/24 172.23.45.0/24 129.228.114.0/23 
129.228.70.0/24 129.228.109.42 129.228.109.83
        force user = nobody
        force group = nobody
        force create mode = 0666
        force directory mode = 0777
        create mode = 0666
        directory mode = 0777
        guest account = vimn

        security = user
        passdb backend = tdbsam
        ntlm auth = yes

        log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
        log level = 2 passdb:5 auth:5
        max log size = 50M

        #Performance Tuning:
        use sendfile = true
        kernel oplocks = no
        strict locking = no

        #FUCK OSX!
        veto files = /.DS_Store/.AppleDesktop/.AppleDB/.AppleDouble/.Temporary Items/
        delete veto files = yes

        printing = cups
        printcap name = cups
        load printers = no
        cups options = raw

[AMS-HATCH]
        comment = HATCH Storage Share (AutoCleaned 30 Days)
        path = /quantum/AMS-HATCH
        browseable = yes
        writable = yes
        guest ok = yes
        force user = nobody
        force group = nobody
        valid users = @LinuxAdmins, vimn, mll
```

As you can see I outhashed the line "hosts allow" so that all IP's can access them, later when all is working I would like to limit access through that (or "hosts deny").

The credentials are checked already multiple times, and they are enterred correctly.
I red something about samba-winbond for non-domain servers to be disabled, but I did not install it, is there a setting I don't know about that I mis or should use?

In the log file of this session I have this:

```
[2018/02/19 11:21:07.724423,  5] 
../source3/auth/server_info_sam.c:122(make_server_info_sam)
  make_server_info_sam: made server info for user vimn -> vimn
[2018/02/19 11:21:07.724461,  3] 
../source3/auth/auth.c:249(auth_check_ntlm_password)
  check_ntlm_password: sam authentication for user [vimn] succeeded
[2018/02/19 11:21:07.724516,  5] 
../source3/auth/auth.c:292(auth_check_ntlm_password)
  check_ntlm_password:  PAM Account for user [vimn] succeeded
[2018/02/19 11:21:07.724537,  2] 
../source3/auth/auth.c:305(auth_check_ntlm_password)
  check_ntlm_password:  authentication for user [vimn] -> [vimn] -> [vimn] 
succeeded
[2018/02/19 11:21:07.725216,  5] 
../source3/passdb/pdb_interface.c:1749(lookup_global_sam_rid)
  lookup_global_sam_rid: looking up RID 513.
[2018/02/19 11:21:07.725264,  5] 
../source3/passdb/pdb_tdb.c:658(tdbsam_getsampwrid)
  pdb_getsampwrid (TDB): error looking up RID 513 by key RID_00000201.
[2018/02/19 11:21:07.725300,  5] 
../source3/passdb/pdb_interface.c:1825(lookup_global_sam_rid)
  Can't find a unix id for an unmapped group
[2018/02/19 11:21:07.725317,  5] 
../source3/passdb/pdb_interface.c:1535(pdb_default_sid_to_id)
  SID S-1-5-21-3363938291-73671434-3978610123-513 belongs to our domain, but 
there is no corresponding object in the database.
```

Password is authenticated correctly, but still the connection is cut-off.

Thanks a lot people.

edit: added the log section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nobody supplied an answer, but the problem does not persist anymore.